# Border-box with 50% width can't fit into one line

Tags: css, width, html-lists, border-box

I set `li` elements for `width: 50%`, in order to separate  the `ul` block into two `li` in one line like the picture below. And here's the [JS bin](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3SrP9.png) for example, with *normalize.css*.

[image: nice arrangement of li]
[Picture 1]

However, the width of `li` needed to be less than 50%, like 49.6% or less. If not, some space showed up between `li` and `li` for unknown reason, even though I'd set the `box-sizing: border-box` and `margin: 0` for `li`.

[image: bad arrangement of li]
[Picture 2]

I know I can use `float: left` to make it work like the first picture, but I want to know why there's space existed in picture 2.

P.S.: I'm using Chrome for my browser, if on Safari, it's okay for 49.5%.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard to know without seeing the code, but I think the issue is that li
 elements on different lines will display with spaces between them. Whitespace doesn't USUALLY make a difference with HTML but in the case of whitespace between li elements it does. So the following will display spaces

```
<ul> 
    <li style="display: inline;">1</li> 
    <li style="display: inline;">2</li> 
    <li style="display: inline;">3</li> 
</ul>
```

But this one won't.

```
<ul> 
    <li style="display: inline;">1</li><li style="display: inline;">2</li><li style="display: inline;">3</li> 
</ul>
```

Here's a codepen for demonstration. If you can't modify the original html, try adding a negative margin.

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/zGRYzm